# Javascript Alert cannot be entered

Tags: javascript

is there any way to block `Enter` Keyboard when an alert box is show up? So user need to press Esc or Click the `Ok` button to remove the alert.

```
<script>
alert('Hello');
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I know, the alert-box is non-configurable, and you can't write scripts to interact with it.

Comment: No. The alert is outside the document and you can't add any event handling to it.

Comment: The only way then use a jquery right? Create custom alert?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the comments before me, the standard javascript alert:

```
alert("hello world!");
```

Is a feature that is handled, styled, and executed by the browser outside the scope of javascript control.

With that said you can do this fairly easily by making a custom popup box.

I'm not going to go over the styling very much, but below is some code you could build on for a styled box:

```
<div id="alertBox" style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:9999;background:white">
  <div id="alertText" style="position:relative;text-align:center;top:45%">
    You must press "esc" to escape!
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript however I will explain in more detail. This is the code:

```
function code(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  return(e.keyCode || e.which);
}

document.onkeypress = function(e){
    var key = code(e);
    if(key == 27){
      //run some code, they pressed the esc key
      document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = "none"; 
    }
};
```

The first 4 lines of code store what key was pressed into a variable called "e".

The document.onkeypress function starts listening for when a key is pressed. The "e" variable is passed into the function and then saved into a variable named "key" for clarity.

The "key" variable is then tested against the "esc" keys number on the keyboard which is 27. If the "key" equals 27 than we run some code, if it does not we ignore the keypress.

The code we run here removes the alert box we made.

I hope that helps!

P.s. This answer does not use jQuery, but jQuery would make it less code if you already have it in your project.

Comment: thank you! part of `if key code == 27` is what i search for my alert now

Comment: helo YAHsaves, key 27 is not working now... any idea why?

Comment: You'd have to give me some code that you applied this too for me to see why. If I copy the html and javascript I provided in my answer into a document it works. So it depends how you take this code and apply it.